# Mips subtraction negative overflow

Tags: binary, mips

Hexadecimal in mips: If I have 0x80000000 and I subtract it by 0xD00000000
my answer is 0X -50000000
is this possible in mips having a negative in or is there another way to write this? That is correct?

Comment: Google "two's complement".

Comment: x + complementx = -1? , -x = complement+1 so 0xB0000000???

Comment: For a 32-bit value, yes.  -x = 2**32 - x, which is equal to the one's complement (all-ones minus x) plus 1, so both numbers would represent the same value.  I don't know MIPS, though...is it 32-bit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember, if you look at the most significant bit, you'll know if you are working with a negative number. For simplicity, let's just look at the four most significant bits.

```
0x80 = 1000 0000
0xD0 = 1101 0000
```

So those values are already negative. You want to subtract them, that is, 0x80 - 0xD0. Well, subtraction is addition (a-b = a + -b), and the whole point of 2's compliment is that you can add signed numbers and get the result you expect. So let's negate 0xD0:

```
1101 0000 # original value
0010 1111 # flip the bits
0011 0000 # add 1
```

If that didn't make sense, ask the all-knowing [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).

Now, we can add the values:

```
1000 0000
0011 0000
---------
1011 0000
```

So if I've done it right, 0x80 - 0xD0 = 0xB0. It's still a negative number (but you don't put a minus sign in front of it, it's implied by the MSBit). And that makes sense, because 0x80 is a very negative number, and 0xD0 is a *less negative number* than 0x80. (Really, it is... 0xFF is -1, the least negative number.)